# Retrieve last 10 weeks dynamically SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, powerbi

I'm using a live connection in Power BI from SSAS Cube Multidimensionnal. I created a named set that gives the last 10 weeks from now. Named set are not working with Power BI. How to do this without Named sets ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `mdx` script to get the data from ssas then you just add the expression for the past 10 weeks to the `WHERE` clause of the script.